# Javascript Error on page, because of loaded jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote some jQuery that checks the location of the person on the page and add some classed.

But when I load the jQuery I see a lot of errors in the browser console.
When scrolling the number of errors increase.

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'refElement.position().top')
Geselecteerd element
```

How can I solve this?

jQuery:

```
(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var sticky = $('.menu-header-product'),
            scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        var elementOffset = jQuery("#productnav").offset();
        if (scroll >= elementOffset.top - 88) sticky.addClass('sticky');
        else sticky.removeClass('sticky');
    });
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var sticky = $('.content'),
            scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        var elementOffset = jQuery("#productnav").offset();
        if (scroll >= elementOffset.top - 88) sticky.addClass('sticky');
        else sticky.removeClass('sticky');
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(document).off("scroll");

            $('a').each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            })
            $(this).addClass('active');

            var target = this.hash;
            $target = $(target);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 88 /**just subtract the height of the fixed html part */
            }, 500, 'swing', function() {
                window.location.hash = target;
                $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
        });
    });

    function onScroll(event) {
        var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('nav a').each(function() {
            var currentLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top - 88 <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top - 125 + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
                $('nav ul li a').removeClass("active");
                currentLink.addClass("active");
            }
            else {
                currentLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery.noConflict());
```

Comment: Remove the `()` in your `position()` and try like this, `if (refElement.position.top - 88 <= scrollPosition && refElement.position.top - 125 + refElement.height > scrollPosition) {...`

Comment: @DavidR Thanks! Tried that, but then the section with the reffering ID does not add the class `active` anymore, when scrolling over it.

Comment: What does the `currentLink` printing when you do a `console.log` ?

Comment: What do you mean with `$(currentLink.attr("href"))` ? it's invalid.

Comment: @DavidR It is not displaying anything in console.log.

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer Why should it be invalid?

Comment: @HenkZ Can you please make a quick fiddle and share us the link to debug further?

Comment: @DavidR See here the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pytduk9q/1/

Comment: Try to use `currentLink` instead of `refElement`

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer Can you give me an example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not written any style for your `.active` class,

I have just added a `color:red` to it and it seems to work fine.

**Working DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/pytduk9q/3/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I know, but this code is giving the errors in my console. I know that the code works fine, but I want to solve the javascript errors.

Comment: No.. I have checked the `console`, There are NO errors! :-) Check again!

Comment: Strange, indeed inside the jsFiddle I also do not see the errors. But on my site, when placing the code, I get the errors. How can I solve this?

Comment: Try clearing your cache and then execute the page. If you still get any error(s), please post it here.

Comment: I tried removing the cache and checked it again, I still get the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'refElement.position().top')`

Comment: Can you give a live to check if possible?

Comment: Yes I can, but I do not want to post it on this forum. Is there I can DM you?

Comment: Thanks, I just sent it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126836/discussion-between-david-r-and-henk-z).